# create a hive table with location clause from local

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Can I create a table with the location clause , and the location is not hdfs but local .

Like we have two flavour of load data

```
1 > load data inpath 
 2 > load data local inpath
```

Comment: to the best of my knowledge and refer to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-CreatingHiveTables I think you should create the table first and then load local data and there is no way to create table by local clause. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a table with local location in HIVE. The location clause must point only to any HDFS location then only we will be able to enjoy the benefits of hadoop and Bigdata.

Load data inpath loads the data from HDFS location to HIVE specified location.

Load data local inpath loads the data from local filesystem location to the HIVE specified location.

So ultimately we are bringing all data into HDFS for processing.